# Minimizing the spectral radius of certain elements of group rings

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $G$ be a finite group. Let $I_{G}$ be the ideal on the group ring $\mathbb{C}[G]$ consisting of elements of the form $\alpha\cdot\sum_{g\in G}g$.

Let $\lambda_{n}(G)$ be the minimum spectral radius of elements of the form $t_{1}g_{1}+\dots+t_{n}g_{n}+I_{G}\in\mathbb{C}[G]/I_{G}$ subject to the conditions that $t_{i}\geq 0$ for all $i$ and $t_{1}+\dots+t_{n}=1$.  Let $\lambda_{n}^{*}(G)$ be the minimum spectral radius of elements of the form $\frac{1}{n}(g_{1}+\dots+g_{n})+I_{G}\in\mathbb{C}[G]/I_{G}$.

What are some estimates or asymptotic estimates of $\lambda_{n}(S_{m})$ and $\lambda_{n}(A_{m})$? What are some estimates of $\lambda_{n}^{*}(S_{m})$ and $\lambda_{n}^{*}(A_{m})$? I may also be interested to see what people have to say about the $\lambda_{n}(G)$ for finite non-abelian groups $G$.

The cases that I am most interested in where $G=S_{m}$ or $G=A_{m}$ are motivated by cryptography. If $(f_{k})_{k\in K}$ are the round permutations for some cryptosystem, then we would want for the eigenvalues $\sum_{k\in K}f_{k}+I_{G}$ to have small modulus for security. However, it is probably not feasible to compute or estimate the spectral radius of $\sum_{k\in K}f_{k}+I_{G}$ whenever $(f_{k})_{k\in K}$ is of cryptographic interest.